# How to handle free() errors in C?

Tags: c, exception, free

Suppose that I have used a `free()` function to free a memory that,for many reasons, I'm not allowed to.
How can I stop my C application from crashing and just generate an error and continue the execution? I don't have try-catch kind of provision here (like C++/java...). Is there any way to ignore this error and continue execution?

If yes,

1. How do you do that?
2. More importantly, is it advisable to do so (continuing execution considering this memory error occurred)?

Thank you

Comment: Behavior depends on the platform and library implementation. You need to be more specific if you want any kind of meaningful answer.

Comment: Are you sure pointer you're passing to `free()` points to a valid memory block? If a call to `free()` crashes, then you have a bigger problem.

Comment: AFAIK free() doesn't terminate program if valid pointer passed to it.

Comment: Suppose we saw code that illustrates your problem.

Comment: @Mihran, if you pass `free` something that wasn't returned by `malloc` (or `calloc`, or `realloc`, etc.), then behavior is undefined. Undefined behavior is allowed to include terminating the program. There are lots of valid pointers that `malloc` didn't return, and lots of invalid pointers that `malloc` *did* return. Validity of the pointer is irrelevant.

Comment: @Rob agree. The word valid is not suitable in this case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is nothing in the C standard that you can use to do what you want. The description of the `free` function is very clear on that (§7.20.3.2 in C99):

> The free function causes the space pointed to by ptr to be deallocated, that is, made
>   available for further allocation. If ptr is a null pointer, no action occurs. *Otherwise, if
>   the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by the calloc, malloc, or
>   realloc function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to free or realloc,
>   **the behavior is undeﬁned.***

Answer (score 10):

It's certainly not advisable. Even if your program's version of `free` correctly detects that the memory you're trying to free cannot be freed, and thus doesn't do any harm itself, you still have a bug in your program — part of the program thought it owned that memory. Who knows what it might have tried to do with that memory before freeing it? Find and fix the bug. Don't just sweep it under the rug.

Answer (score 0):

Freeing invalid memory is a serious bug and should be fixed, as it's possible to corrupt the state of your program. Try using a tool like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org) to spot what's going wrong.

The only pointers you should be using `free` on are those you receive from `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc` or `NULL` pointers. Further you shouldn't use `free` on the same pointer more than once.