# What happen if we free memory which are already free or not malloc?

Tags: c

When I free the `malloc`ed memory which are not allocated using `malloc` than valgraind tool gives me error like:

```
Invalid free() / delete / delete[]
```

**Is it dangerous in embedded C programming?**

In code whenever `malloc` fails than i cannot judge which `malloc`ed pointer i have to release.

Comment: It is dangerous in **Any** kind of C programming.

Comment: *"the `malloc`ed memory which are not allocated using `malloc`"*?  That doesn't make sense.  Either it was `malloc`ed or it wasn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will lead to undefined behavior, most likely heap corruption and/or crashing your program. It's dangerous in any kind of system.

Answer (score 2):

Your program could crash (as everyone replied), and even worse, it could crash much latter than when you have incorrectly called `malloc`. So finding these kind of bugs is hard.

A possible solution, assuming you have access to all your source code and can change it (i.e. assuming that you don't use third parties libraries which you cannot alter) might be to use [Boehm conservative garbage collector](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/), by replacing every occurrence of 
`malloc`, `calloc`etc ... with `GC_MALLOC` or `GC_CALLOC`after having `#include`d `<gc/gc.h>` (and then, you won't bother calling `free` anymore).

Boehm's garbage collector being conservative, it does have a small probability to leak (because it handles every word on your call stack as a possible pointer, even if that word in fact don't carry a dereferencable pointer, but e.g. an integer or a float).

And you did not explain what embedded C programming means for you. In some industries and contexts, critical embedded C code (like the one making your aircraft flying) is not even allowed to call `malloc` or to use dynamically allocated heap data.

Comment: +1 for highlighting the side-effect nightmare of a intermittent failure at 'random' times, 'random' places, in a different thread and in code that you have already tested and proved OK.

Answer (score 1):

If you call `free` on memory that was not allocated with `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc`, or if you call it on memory that you have already freed, you'll get undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is dangerous for embedded programming. It is almost always crash you software.

Comment: Why `Only Embedded` programming?

Comment: Because the OP asked about embedded specifically... you should be asking Sam this question, not Sergey :)

Comment: Because question was exactly about that. BTW, I believe this question should be closed as duplicate. For example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530306/how-to-handle-free-errors-in-c and lot of q-a on that topic on stackoverflow.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi: It is a Standard guaranteed UB, So just limiting it to say for `embedded programming` is mis-leading.And If you feel this Q should have been closed as duplicate then You should mark it as duplicate and vote for closing it instead of answering it.

Comment: @Als I've no privilege to mark it or vote for closing, so I belive you'll get the right decision here. UB means that nobody knows what happens. But I believe all knows here what happens next in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You will get undefined behaviour, typically memory corruption by freeing memory that hasn't been allocated.

I don't see how you can say that you don't know which pointer result from a malloc operation has failed?

It's really quite simple.

Declare your pointers and set them to null.

Use malloc to allocate your memory. Only use malloc on pointers that are already null (to prevent memory leaks due to reassigning a pointer to a memory block to another one). If the malloc fails then the pointer will remain null.

When it comes to freeing memory allocated by a malloc operation, only perform the free operation if the pointer is not null and once freed set that pointer to null.